# How to resolve this pip install error (when trying to install mxnet)?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, legacy, mxnet

I am working with anaconda & run the cmd:`pip instal mxnet`.
I already tried to upgrade `pip,wheel,setuptools`.
& to instal it with `--no-use-pep517`,`--no-cache-dir`
& `--pre` as recommended here:https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-eror-legacy-instal-failure & instaled visualC++build-tools.
Still gettinthe following:eror-legacy-instal-failure

```
  Collectin mxnet
    Using cached mxnet-1.7.0.post2-py2.py3-none-      win_amd64.whl(33.1MB)
  Collectin numpy<1.17.0,>=1.8.2
    Using cached numpy-1.16.6.zip (5.1MB)
    Preparingmetadata(setup.py)...done
  Req already satisfied:reqs<2.19.0,>=2.18.4 in       c:\path\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from mxnet)(2.18.4)
  Collecting graphviz<0.9.0,>=0.8.1
    Using cached graphviz-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl(16kB)
  Requirement already satisfied:idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\path\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet)(2.6)
  Requirement already satisfied:certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\path\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet)(2022.9.14)
  Requirement already satisfied:chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\path\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet)(3.0.4)
  Requirement alredy satisfied:urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\path\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet)(1.22)
  Building wheels for collected packages:numpy
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py)
    eror:subprocess-exited-with-eror

    × python setup.py bdist_wheel didnt run successfuly
    │ exitcode:1
    ╰─>[264lines of output]
  Runing from numpy source dir.
  C:\path\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal-tt_fysn_\numpy_4c416a770c4e4a078f07d959c6bf4a7c\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py:476:SyntaxWarning:"is" with a literal. Did u mean "=="?
    return is_string(s)& ('*'in s or'?'is s)
  blas_opt_info blas_mkl_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs mkl_rt not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE 

  blis_info:
  No modle named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs blis not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILBLE
  openblas_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs openblas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
  get_default_fcompiler:matching types:'['gnu','intelv','absoft','compaqv','intelev','gnu95','g95','intelvem','intelem','flang']'
  customize GnuFCompiler
  couldnt locate executable g77,f77
  customize IntelVisualFCompiler
  couldnt locate executable ifort,executable ifl
  customize AbsoftFCompiler
  couldnt locate executable f90
  customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
  couldnt locate executable DF
  customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
  couldnt locate executable efl
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  couldnt locate executable gfortran,executable f95
  customize G95FCompiler
  couldnt locate executable g95
  customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler,IntelEM64TFCompiler
  couldnt locate executable efort,executable efc
  customize PGroupFlangCompiler
  couldnt locate executable flang
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs tatlas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs satlas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\path\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal-tt_fysn_\numpy_4c416a770c4e4a078f07d959c6bf4a7c\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639:UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/)libs not found.
      dirs to search for the libs can be specified inthe
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section[atlas])orby setting
      the ATLAS env var.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs blas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\path\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal-tt_fysn_\numpy_4c416a770c4e4a078f07d959c6bf4a7c\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639:UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/)libs not found.
      dirs to search for the libs can be specified inthe
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section[blas])orby setting
      the BLAS env var.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE
  C:\path\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal-tt_fysn_\numpy_4c416a770c4e4a078f07d959c6bf4a7c\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639:UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/)sources not found.
      Dirs to search for the sources can be specified inthe
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section[blas_src])orby setting
      the BLAS_SRC env var
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILBLE

  The cmd "svnversion" is either typed wrong orcant befind.
  non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils':'site.cfg'
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs mkl_rt not found in['C:\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs openblas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs openblas,lapack not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs satlas,satlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs satlas,satlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\path\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal-tt_fysn_\numpy_4c416a770c4e4a078f07d959c6bf4a7c\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639:UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/)libs not found.
      dirs to search for the libs can be specified inthe
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section[lapack])orby setting
      the LAPACK env var.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\path\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal-tt_fysn_\numpy_4c416a770c4e4a078f07d959c6bf4a7c\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639:UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/)sources not found.
      dirs to search for the sources can be specified inthe
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section[lapack_src])orby setting
      the LAPACK_SRC env var.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\path\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:265:UserWarning:Unknown distribution option:'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  runing bdist_wheel
  runing build
  runing config_cc
  unifing config_cc,config,build_clib,build_ext,build comm&s --compiler options
  runing config_fc
  unifing config_fc,config,build_clib,build_ext,build comm&s --fcompiler options
  runing build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  creating build
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
  creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
  building lib "npymath" sources
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  eror:Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
 [end of output]
```

note:This eror originates from a subprocess,& is likely not a problem with pip
EROR:Failed building wheel for numpy
runing setup.py clean for numpy
eror:subprocess-exited-with-eror

```
  × python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
  │ exit code:1
  ╰─>[10 lines of output]
  runing from numpy source dir.
  `setup.py clean` is not supported,use one of the following instead:
    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files,doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to ur comm& to use it anyway if u must (unsupported).
 [end of output]

note:This eror originates from a subprocess,& is likely not a problem with pip.
```

eror:Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
Failed to build numpy
instaling collected packages:numpy,graphviz,mxnet
Attempting uninstal:numpy
Found existing instalation:numpy 1.23.5
Uninstaling numpy-1.23.5:
Successfully uninstaled numpy-1.23.5
runing setup.py instal for numpy ... eror
eror:subprocess-exited-with-eror

× runing setup.py instal for numpy did not run successfully.
│ exit code:1
╰─>[269 lines of output]
runing from numpy source dir.

```
  Note:if u need reliable uninstal behavior,then instalwith pip insted of usin `setup.py instal`:
    - `pip instal .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source release)
    - `pip instal numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs mkl_rt not fond in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  blis_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs blis not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE
  openblas_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs openblas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
  get_default_fcompiler:matching types:'['gnu','intelv','absoft','compaqv','intelev','gnu95','g95','intelvem','intelem','flang']'
  customize GnuFCompiler
  couldnt locate executable g77,executable f77
  customize IntelVisualFCompiler
  couldnt locate executable ifort,ifl
  customize AbsoftFCompiler
  couldnt locate executable f90
  customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
  couldnt locate executable DF
  customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
  couldnt locate executable efl
  customize Gnu95FCompiler
  couldnt locate executable gfortran,f95
  customize G95FCompiler
  couldnt locate executable g95
  customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler,IntelEM64TFCompiler
  couldnt locate executable efort,efc
  customize PGroupFlangCompiler
  couldnt locate executable flang
  don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs tatlas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs satlas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_blas_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  accelerate_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\path\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal-tt_fysn_\numpy_4c416a770c4e4a078f07d959c6bf4a7c\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639:UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/)libs not found.
      dirs to search for the libs can be specified inthe
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section[atlas])orby setting
      the ATLAS env var.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs blas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\path\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal-tt_fysn_\numpy_4c416a770c4e4a078f07d959c6bf4a7c\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639:UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/)libs not found.
      dirs to search for the libs can be specified inthe
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section[blas])orby settin
      the BLAS envi. var.
    self.calc_info()
  blas_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\path\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal-tt_fysn_\numpy_4c416a770c4e4a078f07d959c6bf4a7c\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639:UserWarning:
      Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/)sources not found.
      dirs to search for the sources can be specified inthe
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section[blas_src])orby setting
      the BLAS_SRC env var.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  The cmd"svnversion" is eithertyped wrong orcant be find.
  non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils':'site.cfg'
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs mkl_rt not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs openblas not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_clapack_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs openblas,lapack not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryig from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs satlas,satlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs satlas,satlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\lib
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack_atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\path\anaconda3\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  lapack_info:
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
    libs lapack not found in['C:\\path\\anaconda3\\lib','C:\\','C:\\path\\anaconda3\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\path\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal-tt_fysn_\numpy_4c416a770c4e4a078f07d959c6bf4a7c\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639:UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/)libs not found.
      dirs to search for the libs can be specified inthe
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file(section[lapack])orby setting
      the LAPACK env var.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\path\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal-tt_fysn_\numpy_4c416a770c4e4a078f07d959c6bf4a7c\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639:UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/)sources not found.
      dirs to search for the sources can be specified inthe
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section[lapack_src])orby setting
      the LAPACK_SRC env var.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  C:\path\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:265:UserWarning:Unknown distribution option:'define_macros'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  runing instal
  C:\path\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\comm&\instal.py:34:SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning:setup.py instal is deprecated. Use build & pip & other st&ards-based tools.
    warnings.warn(
  runing build
  runing config_cc
  unifing config_cc,config,build_clib,build_ext,build comm&s --compiler opts
  runing config_fc
  unifing config_fc,config,build_clib,build_ext,build comm&s --fcompiler options
  runing build_src
  build_src
  building py_modules sources
  building lib "npymath" sources
  No module named'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; tryin from distutils
  eror:Microsoft VisualC++14.0 or greater is required.Get it with "MicrosoftC++BuildTools":https://...
 [end of output]
```

note:This eror originates from a subprocess,& is likely not a problem with pip.
Rolling back uninstal of numpy
movin to c:\path\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.23.5.dist-info
from C:\path\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages~umpy-1.23.5.dist-info
movin to c:\path\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy
from C:\path\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages~umpy
movin to c:\path\anaconda3\scripts\f2py.exe
from C:\path\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstal-xr8_bke0\f2py.exe
eror:legacy-instal-failure

× Encountered eror while tryin to instal pckage.
╰─> numpy

note:This is an issue with the pkg mentioned above,not pip
hint:See above for output from the failure

Comment: The error mentions that numpy version 1.16.6 is being used, but MXNet requires numpy version 1.8.2 or higher.

Comment: cringe, I upgraded numpy..

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: You got a new error now?

Comment: I still get the legacy-install-failure

Comment: Could you update the question with the most recent error message please?

Comment: Thought that I solved this by reinstalling C++ building tools - then I was able to install mxnet. But now, I get the following error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74893742/how-to-solve-attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-bool/74893992#74893992

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the version of numpy you are trying to install.

The version of numpy you are installing, 1.16.6, does work with older versions of Python like 3.7, but does not work with Python 3.11.

At of the time of writing, `mxnet` has updated so this should not be an issue. However, if you need to install a package that is still referencing a version of numpy that won't work, here is how you can install it anyway.

You can do this by using the `--no-deps` flag to override the module trying to install an old version.

```
pip install --no-deps mxnet # or other module with outdated package requirements
pip install -U numpy # install the most recent version of numpy (or other package in question
```

Note: At the time of writing, the newest version of numpy is 1.24.3