# facing issues in installing koalas for Python version 3.8.10 (AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool')

Tags: python, numpy, spark-koalas

According to this document https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/install.html

System info:

```
numpy   1.24.3  
koalas  1.8.2 
pyspark 3.4.0 
Python  3.8.10
```

Facing Issue when trying to read csv file

```
import databricks.koalas as ks
import time
import numpy as np
df_koalas=ks.read_csv('train.csv')
```

**AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'**

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'.
`np.bool` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
```

Comment: Please read the error message. It has all of the information you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74893742/how-to-solve-attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-bool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Koalas hasn't been maintained as an individual project in a while, as [its functionality was incorporated directly into PySpark](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34849) as of Spark 3.2.0. It is not compatible with recent NumPy versions. You need to migrate to [the new Spark Pandas API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/index.html).