# module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int' error from yolov5 files

Tags: python, numpy, model, yolo, yolov5

I'm trying to train my dataset by using yolov5, but I got module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int' error when I start the training and this error coming from yolov5 files probably. I added the screenshot of this error. Could you help me to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74893742/how-to-solve-attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-bool)

Answer (score 1):

This attribute in NumPy has been deprecated. You have `two` solutions:

1. During the installation of program requirements, install exactly the version mentioned in the `requirements.txt` file. That is, an older version.
2. Clone the new version of `yolov5` from `GitHub`.