# brew installation of numpy is not working

Tags: homebrew

I installed numpy with brew as seen here:

```
(venv6) me:pcode me$ brew install numpy
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json

==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json

Warning: numpy 1.26.3 is already installed and up-to-date.
```

But then

```
Python 3.8.0 (v3.8.0:fa919fdf25, Oct 14 2019, 10:23:27) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

When I deactive the virtual environment (venv6) I get the same error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `hombrew`? Surely the best solution would be to use `pip install numpy`, that should fix your error.

Comment: When I pip install numpy it only download 1.24 not the latest version and there is a bug in 1.24 as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74893742/how-to-solve-attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-bool

Comment: I downgraded to 1.23.1 but it turns out there is a bug in that one too.

Comment: I would always use pip or pip3 for installing Python packages. Installation of Pip is relatively simple, and should just be just for your users

Comment: This command should install pip for your own personal (not global) user -`python -m pip install`

Comment: Can you not choose which version of numpy to install? One of the answers to the stack overflow link you sent solved that problem too.

Comment: I decided to bite the bullet and install python 3.11.7.  After all, I can't use 3.8 forever.  That solved the numpy problem but of course I'm spending 2 to 3 hours updating all of my old packages and it is not fun.